# Retrieve document with an HTTP request CouchDB 3.0.0

Tags: curl, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I'm a beginner in CouchDB, and on the net I've read that is possible to run Mango queries with an HTTP request. I've tried hard, but I'm unable to rut queries like this.

This is the command

```
C:\>curl -X POST http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/movielens/_find -d @query.json
{"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}
```

this is the body of the json file:

```
{"selector": { "Genres": {"$elemMatch": {"$eq": "Drama"}}}}
```

From what I understood, I don't know where I'm wrong. So, how do I do to run this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type`  in your header to `application/json`.

Try this:
`curl -X POST http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/movielens/_find --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @query.json`

Comment: I had been looking for a solution for days, thank you very much